# System classes while enabling Assertions, what are they?

Tags: java, assertions

What do they mean with System classes in the following statement taken from [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)?

> To enable assertions at various granularities, use the
>   -enableassertions, or -ea, switch. To disable assertions at various granularities, use the -disableassertions, or -da, switch. You specify
>   the granularity with the arguments that you provide to the switch:
>
> - no arguments
>     Enables or disables assertions in all classes except **system classes**.
> - ...

(emphasis mine).

Comment: To enable assertions in all system classes, use a different switch: -enablesystemassertions, or -esa. Similarly, to disable assertions in system classes, use -disablesystemassertions, or -dsa... they also apply to system classes (which do not have an explicit class loader)

Comment: @nachokk But that doesn't say what system classes are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"System classes" are those loaded by the boot class loader. For all intents and purposes, this means the classes documented in the standard Java APIs.

Comment: So basically only java.lang? What would be the use anyway?

Comment: Java.*, javax.*, org.w3c, etc. Many thousands of classes!

Comment: I thought only java.lang and the unnamed package are loaded implicitly.

Comment: You're just thinking of things that are implicitly imported by the compiler. I'm talking about a runtime thing, completely different.

Comment: ok I see man, I got confused, thanks for clarifying.